# Kendo grid selection entire row

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I want kendoGrid to *select the entire row*.

I have to have this set:
`scrollable: { virtual: true }`
and without paging data

Sample: [Kendo UI Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UwoHU)

Just click on *Brazil* to select the row but it just selects the cell.

Comment: Did you try to write some code?

Comment: I'm confused. First grid in your demo lets you select entire row, and second grid lets you select a cell. Look like the first grid is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the second grid !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Kendo's documentation:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-selectable

set `selectable: "row"` in your grid settings

Comment: I have to keep : "scrollable: { virtual: true }"

Comment: This must be a new feature cuz it's the first time I hear about it, but after checking their documentation I don't think they are mutually exclusive, you can use both together without affecting each other.
For more info refer to their official documentation, I suggest you bookmark it for future reference http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data
This is used for large amount of data

Answer (score 1):

Use `selectable: "row"` instead to make whole row selectable.
[Check the demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/selection)

Comment: I have to keep : "scrollable: { virtual: true }"